# Multiple columns extracted from one Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a (parsed) datetime column in my Pandas dataframe. I now need to generate multiple columns based on this one column, one with the year, one with the month, the hour, the day of the week etcetera. I'm currently doing a number of individual applies but it is a large dataset and I'm iterating over the df multiple times. Is there a better pattern to accomplish this? Can an apply return a dataframe that I then paste behind it?

Comment: What is the `dtype` here? If it's already `datetime` then you can just do `df[['year','day','month','day_of_week']] = df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month, df['date'].dt.day, df['date'].dt.dayofweek` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the `dtype` is already `datetime` then you can use the vectorised datetime accessor `dt` to add the columns:

```
In [11]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2016,1,1), end = dt.datetime(2016,1,10))})
df

Out[11]:
        date
0 2016-01-01
1 2016-01-02
2 2016-01-03
3 2016-01-04
4 2016-01-05
5 2016-01-06
6 2016-01-07
7 2016-01-08
8 2016-01-09
9 2016-01-10

In [13]:    
df['year'],df['month'],df['day'], df['day_of_week'] = df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month, df['date'].dt.day, df['date'].dt.dayofweek
df

Out[13]:
        date  year  month  day  day_of_week
0 2016-01-01  2016      1    1            4
1 2016-01-02  2016      1    2            5
2 2016-01-03  2016      1    3            6
3 2016-01-04  2016      1    4            0
4 2016-01-05  2016      1    5            1
5 2016-01-06  2016      1    6            2
6 2016-01-07  2016      1    7            3
7 2016-01-08  2016      1    8            4
8 2016-01-09  2016      1    9            5
9 2016-01-10  2016      1   10            6
```